# Building Options for Select from Elixir Map

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Assuming this data_set,

```
 %{"ACTION" => "avail.datacenters",
"DATA" => [%{"ABBR" => "dallas", "DATACENTERID" => 2,
  "LOCATION" => "Dallas, TX, USA"},
%{"ABBR" => "fremont", "DATACENTERID" => 3,
  "LOCATION" => "Fremont, CA, USA"},
%{"ABBR" => "atlanta", "DATACENTERID" => 4,
  "LOCATION" => "Atlanta, GA, USA"},
%{"ABBR" => "newark", "DATACENTERID" => 6, "LOCATION" => "Newark, NJ, USA"},
%{"ABBR" => "london", "DATACENTERID" => 7,
  "LOCATION" => "London, England, UK"},
%{"ABBR" => "tokyo", "DATACENTERID" => 8, "LOCATION" => "Tokyo, JP"},
%{"ABBR" => "singapore", "DATACENTERID" => 9,
  "LOCATION" => "Singapore, SG"},
%{"ABBR" => "frankfurt", "DATACENTERID" => 10,
  "LOCATION" => "Frankfurt, DE"},
%{"ABBR" => "shinagawa1", "DATACENTERID" => 11,
  "LOCATION" => "Tokyo 2, JP"}], "ERRORARRAY" => []}}
```

In Ruby, i could do

```
formatted_array_of_hashes = data_set.each.map{ |h| { h["LOCATION"] => h["DATACENTERID"] }}
```

and then

```
merged_hash = Hash[*formatted_array_of_hashes.map(&:to_a).flatten]
```

... and i would have  location,datacenterid to use in a select Tag.

Please how can i achieve something similar in Elixir?

Any Pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated

Comment: Like this: `for %{"LOCATION" => k, "DATACENTERID" => v} <- data_set, into: %{}, do: {k, v}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for`, return a 2-tuple in the `do` and put it `into: %{}`:

```
map = for %{"LOCATION" => k, "DATACENTERID" => v} <- data_set, into: %{}, do: {k, v}
```

If you want to use this with `Phoenix.HTML.Form.select/4` though, you don't need to build the map. You can pass a list of tuples. That way you won't lose the ordering of the elements like you would with maps since maps are unordered.

```
select _, _, for(%{"LOCATION" => k, "DATACENTERID" => v} <- data_set, do: {k, v})
```

---

Sidenote: your Ruby code can also be simplified to:

```
hash = data_set.map { |h| [h["LOCATION"], h["DATACENTERID"]] }.to_h
```

Comment: Wow!, Thank you so much for Simplifying my Ruby Code.Somehow, the example code returns an empty Map. When used with the select, i get a Protocol.UndefinedError,
protocol Enumerable not implemented

Comment: Ah, is your list in `data_set["DATA"]`? Then change `<- data_set` to `<- data_set["DATA"]`. If the pattern doesn't match, `for` silently ignores that value.

Comment: Thank You so Much!

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Phoenix.HTML v3.2 has this function:

```
options_for_select(options, selected_values)
```

Returns options to be used inside a select.

```
options_for_select(["Admin": "admin", "User": "user"], "admin")
#=> <option value="admin" selected="selected">Admin</option>
#=> <option value="user">User</option>
```

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#options_for_select/2